# "ORA-06413 Connection not open" ERROR and "ORA-12154 TNS could not identify the connect identifier specified" ERROR

Tags: oracle10g, powerbuilder

I am having a hard time for connecting powerbuilder ide(12.6) to oracle database(10g xe). Can anyone provide me the step by step process to connect to oracle 10g xe database through powerbuilder database profile(O10 oracle 10g). When I tried to connect it would give connection not found error.
Also,
1)When i give (server name = host:port/apex) in the database profile, It would give connection not found error
2)When i give (server name = XE) in the database profile, It would give ORA-12154 TNS could not identify the connect identifier specified.
Please help me with this issue

Comment: Can you establish a connection through the database painter?  Which driver(s) have you tried?

Comment: 010 oracle 10g driver(native driver) in the database profile.

Comment: The server name is usually the TNSNAME for the connection.
Your TNSNAMES.ORA will have server name = host:port/apex.